# Is there a way to make GridView selectable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making an Uber-like website for a class project. In the code below I load data from a table in my database into a `DataTable` and then show the data in `GridView`.

Is there was a way to make gridview selectable? So if the person selects the first row of the grid and then presses a button, something will happen?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from LoggedIn where UserOccupation= @UserOccupation", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserOccupation", "Driver");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ad.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the most easy way is to add a button to the grid view.

the problem is if you just allow a "click" on a row, then then you have to spend time + effort to show/make the row highlight.

So, it is much easier to just drop a button into the grid view.

And I WILL show/note that once you drop that button on the row, then you CAN have a single click on the row to do the same as the button.

You can add this to the markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="Select"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, so your (nice) simple code will fill the grid. Now the above WILL add a button to the first row. If you don't like that, then add this code snip to the gridview on row create:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated

    Dim myRow As GridViewRow = e.Row

    Dim myCell As TableCell = myRow.Cells(0)
    myRow.Cells.Remove(myCell)
    myRow.Cells.Add(myCell)

End Sub
```

So, the above will move the button to the end of the grid from the first row.

So if you just drop the button, you get this:

[image]

But, I like the button at the end of the grid, so if you add above code, then you get this:

[image]

NOTE careful - note SUPER DUPER careful:
the key magic that makes this work is the CommandArguemnt

this tag in the button: CommandName="Select"

(select is not a guess or some name - it MUST be the keyword select).

Now, with the above button, then a click on the row will fire the selected Index changed event.

In that event, you can get the selected Index

eg:

```
    Debug.Print("row sel = " & GridView1.SelectedIndex)
    Dim mygridrow As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow

    Debug.Print("Hotel name = " & mygridrow.Cells(4).Text)
```

Last but not least:

do you really want this to fire with just a click on the row - not have to click on that button?

Ok then add this routine:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row."
    End If
End Sub
```

NOTE again: You MUST have that button on the grid for the above row-select to work. If you want, you can hide the button with a style="display:none", but you STILL need the one button on the gird - even if you hide it. So now the the button click or a click anywhere on the row will fire/trigger the rowindex changed event as we have above.

And for the row trick to work, you also have to add this to the page heading markup:

```
EnableEventValidation = "false"
```

eg: the above goes here:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="GridRowSel.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="WebEasy.GridRowSel"
EnableEventValidation = "false"%>
```

So not really 100% convinced that you want the row click - but above does work for a button, and if you really want the row click, then you can add that 2nd routine, and also don't forget the EnableEventValidation = "false" in the page heading markup.

## Edit: comments question - selecting rows.

Well, the above was just a example. If one was to want the user say to select a bunch of rows.

This this approach:

Say this gv:

```
<h3>Hotels</h3>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="40%"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<br />

<asp:Button ID="cmdShowSelected" runat="server" 
    Text="Show Selected hotels"
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdShowSelected_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Code to load gv:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GridView1.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And code for the button below the gv:

```
Protected Sub cmdShowSelected_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim sPKList As String = ""
    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim pkID As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
        Dim chkbox As CheckBox = gRow.FindControl("chkSel")

        If chkbox.Checked Then
            If sPKList <> "" Then sPKList &= ","

            sPKList &= pkID

        End If
    Next

    Label1.Text = $"List of PK id selected = {sPKList}"

End Sub
```

And we now have this result:

[image]

Comment: Not very prety,, Is it ?

Comment: Must be missing  something here? We talking about 3 lines of code, and we have a row click. The issue is a row click is NOT the same as a row selecting, or setting the GV row selected (index). However, in 9 out 10 cases the "whole" point here is to not use a GV row selectior, but in fact adopt a row click. They are 2 difference concepts, and the fact that we have both choices? Well, my suggest is going for a simple button or row click as a "alternative" to that of forcing a GV selected row index to fire. So, we talking about 2 VERY different concepts. 2-3 lines of code for row click is pretty!

Comment: OK, but how can the user know which row was selected? Some GUI feadback for the selection click is needed, especially when the botton is headen

Comment: Well, in the case of actually selecting rows, see my edit. It makes a whole lot more sense to just drop in a check box into the GV. See my edit. So, as always, "context of the final goal matters here. Triggering and setting the GV object model to get the "selected" row index and setting to fire is a VAST VAST different question then wanting to select a bunch of rows in a GV. But, see my edit as to how that task would and could be approached. in fact, my point is OFTEN we don't want to use nor care about the selected index object model of the Gv - just plain jane code tends to be better choice.